# Python file prints wrong version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow latest version ie 2.3.0. When I run "pip show tensorflow" in cmd it shows

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\dhiraj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: protobuf, tensorflow-estimator, wrapt, six, astunparse, h5py, numpy, tensorboard, wheel, keras-preprocessing, absl-py, termcolor, google-pasta, gast, scipy, opt-einsum, grpcio
Required-by:
```

But when I run `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.version.VERSION)` in a py file it shows `1.14.0`.
Why is it showing lower version and how to import the latest version?

Comment: What is the version of python are you running the py file with?: python --version

Comment: import sys
print(sys.version)
This gives output 3.7.6

Comment: in cmd it is Python 3.7.2

Comment: Have you tried using this in a controlled environment, for example, using virtualenv?

Comment: Actually I'm new to python. Could you please explain how to use and what is a virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks Ayushya. It worked when I ran it under a controlled env via Anaconda.